# Using Atom editor is there a way to have my Ruby test results rolled up

Tags: ruby, atom-editor

The IntelliJ / RubyMine IDE gives me a visual rollup of my Ruby test results so that I can see a summary of tests passing or failing.

[image: IntelliJ Test Rollup]

This gives me a nice visual way of summarizing test success / failure without having to scroll through lots of logs.

How can I achieve the same outcome using Atom?

Comment: There are packages for this depending upon whether you use RSpec, Cucumber, etc. Do a package search and install the one that suits your needs.